# Video Migration from MySQL

Tags: migrations, 7, files

I have a video link and the video is there in my FTP. I need to migrate videos from mysql to DRUPAL database. Video complete path is stored in mysql database at present. In this process I  dont want to transfer videos from this FTP, instead I want to link somehow to the video-upload field of my content type. Is this achievable ? Is there a module to do this? I have used feeds module for migration but int that I can not migrate videos.

Content type: Sports 
Fields: Sports Type(Text) and Sports Video(Video upload)

I have a video link in my existing database. I want to migrate or somehow link the video to the Sports Video field.

Comment: Do these video's need to become file entities (file_entity module), or atoms (scald module)?

Comment: How do you want to show the video to your visitors? As a link or in a certain player?

Comment: I want to show as a video. In short they should function like a uploaded video itself. (using video module).

Comment: @dmsmidt Yes videos need to become file entities.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the video stored somewhere else and you don't need to consider the video as a managed Drupal file, then you could just migrate the 'video url' to a text field or a custom field type.

Depending on how you would like to output the video to your visitors you could create your own field formatter. And use the stored 'video url' as a source for your video player.

Comment: I have all video in FTP. I want to migrate those videos. And it should come as a managed file itslef. During the migration how can i do that? Is there a module which supports this ? Like link files using urls and crates an entry in managed file table?  I have used feeds module at present.